# Launch script after dockercloud/logrotate rotate log

Tags: linux, docker, logrotate

I'm using DockerCloud for my RESTful API micro services and I use LogDNA to see log of logs of my containers. I use logspout to send log to LogDNA and it's working great until dockercloud/logrotate rotate my containers log. Then, logspout seems to stop working and I need to restart the container. This bug has been documented and reproduce (https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout/issues/309).

Until this is resolve, I'd like to automatically restart the logspout container when dockercloud/logrotate occurs. My idea was to listen to a log file and when logrotate occurs, lauch a script that restart logspout but haven't found a log to check.

Any ideas on how I could restart logspout container when a logrotate occurs?

Comment: Ideas...for where to find a log to check??  Please be clear with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someone who made a docker image that restart logspout after size of containers log has been reduced. (https://hub.docker.com/r/ograhl/logspout-restart/)

I haven't been able to make it works but I took the script run.sh from it and modify it like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

last_logbytes=0

while true
do

  # Sum up size of all log files
  logbytes=`ls -s /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log | awk '{sum+=$1;} END {print sum;}'`

  if [ $logbytes -lt $last_logbytes ]; then

    # Size has been reduced since last poll; Restart logspout
    echo "Restarting Logspout..."
    docker restart f4f5159fe595 #This is logspout container id
  fi

  last_logbytes=$logbytes

  sleep 10

done
```

I have edited /etc/rc.local to launch this script on boot.

Since this solution run every 10 secondes, there is some log that are lost. Until logspout fixes the issue, we can live with this.